# Pointer to int. C++

Tags: c++, pointers, int

I need to pass to function pointer to int.
Now if I want to pass 5 I'm doing it like this:

```
int * i = NULL;
int b = 5;
i = &b;
```

Is there any better way to write it shorter?

I want to pass bytes that are in i int to this function:

```
void Write2Asm(void* pxAddress, BYTE * MyBytes,  int size)
```

Comment: @Hooch instead of Null you should consider using nullptr - it's std.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's wrong with doing : `int i = 5; func(&i);`?

Comment: @Hooch I know it's "just" a wording but I believe that it's important: You're not passing five, what're doing is you're passing **address of a variable** which happen to have value five.

Comment: `nullptr` is not standard yet.

Comment: @AndreyT one can say that it's more than certain that it will be so it is better to start using it in order to be up to date with new std.

Comment: Being "up to date with the new std" does not require one to use `nullptr`. The "traditional" way does not go anywhere.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I agree with @AndreyT, and besides, *being up to date* depends on your compiler being *up to date* which will not be true for all users for different reasons.

Comment: @Andrey "the traditional way" is (technically) incorrect (special case has to be made for 0) that's why (amongst other reasons) nullptr was introduced. Any modern compiler supports nullptr and if someone doesn't use modern compiler (the most up-to-date ver) s/he's doing disservice - and it's not up to date with a language. So I absolutely dissagree and Null, NULL, or null shoudn't be used in modern code. If you dissagree with me then you're wrong. But don't listen to me, ask others.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "special case for 0". It is exactly the same "special case" that takes place when you assign a floating-point value to an integer variable or vice versa. It is the same "special case" that takes place when you assign a pointer value to a `bool` variable. This "special case" is called *standard conversion*. Standard conversions are and will always be present in the language. True, there are problems with not having a dedicated constant for null pointer (which is why we'll have `nullptr`), but initialization of a pointer, as in the above example, is not one of them.

Comment: As for "asking others"... I am "others" :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just pass &b to the function; no need for an intermediate pointer variable.

Comment: One more question. Can I use (PBYTE)&i where int i = 5. Funtion realy need pointer to bytes

Comment: @Hooch: Sure. You can do that.

Answer (score 5):

Why to create a pointer variable?. Why can't you do it like this?.

```
int b = 5;
func(&b)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void f(int *i)
{
  //...
}

int b = 5;
f(&b);
```

is enough!

Answer (score -1):

There are a few old C APIs that always take arguments by pointer, even if they're effectively read-only booleans etc..  I'm not recommending it - more for interest's sake - but if you want to go the whole hog you could do something hackish like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X(int n) : n_(n) { std::cout << "X()\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout << "~X()\n"; }
    operator int&() { return n_; }
    operator const int() const { return n_; }
    int* operator&() { return &n_; }
    const int* operator&() const { return &n_; }
    int n_;
};

// for a function that modifies arguments like this you'd typically
// want to use the modified values afterwards, so wouldn't use
// temporaries in the caller, but just to prove this more difficult
// case is also possible and safe...
void f(int* p1, int* p2)
{
    std::cout << "> f(&" << *p1 << ", &" << *p2 << ")\n";
    *p1 += *p2;
    *p2 += *p1;
    std::cout << "< f() &" << *p1 << ", &" << *p2 << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    // usage...
    f(&X(5), &X(7));

    std::cout << "post\n";
}
```

Crucially, the temporaries are valid until after the function call `f(...)` exits.